# Deconstructing a recursive process - SICP

Tags: lisp, scheme, tail-recursion, sicp

Consider the following definition:

```
   (define foo
     (lambda (x y)
        (if (= x y)
            0
            (+ x (foo (+ x 1) y)))))
```

What is the test expression? (write the actual expression, not its value)

I would think it is just (if (= x y) but the MIT 6.001 On Line Tutor is not accepting that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test would be:

```
(= x y)
```

That's the expression that actually returns a boolean value, and the behaviour of the `if` conditional expression depends on it - if it's `#t` (or in general: any *non-false* value) the *consequent* part will be executed: `0`. Only if it's `#f` the *alternative* part will be executed: `(+ x (foo (+ x 1) y))`.

Comment: scheme interprets anything not #f as true for the purpose of IF, COND, OR, and AND statements.